# HTML Background without CSS (Need Different BackGrounds for JS tooltip)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi 
 I want to use a Java Script ToolTip,in tooltip every background will be different depending on item we are currently hovering so  I cant Use Css to do set backgound - I Tried different methods the best method was using tables, but in table , background image started (almost) from lower half of the box!
 What Should i Do? 
 Thx in Advance

```css
*{
 margin:0;
}

.MainContainer{
 height:270px;
 width:230px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow:0.3px 0.2px 0.3px #66FFFF;
 z-index:0;
 padding:1px;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.NameContainer{
 position:relative;
 height:40px;
 background-color:black;
 z-index:2;
 border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
 opacity:0.7;
 padding:2px;
}
.typeImg{
 margin:3px;
 position: relative;
 top:-42px;
 float:right;
 z-index:3;
}
.heroName{
 margin:8px;
 position: relative;
 top:-42px;
 float:left;
 z-index:3;
 font-family: KoreanFont,georgia,serif;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-size:20px;
 color:white;
}
.SpellContainer{
 position:relative;
 height:55px;
 top:168px;
 background-color:black;
 z-index:2;
 border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;
 opacity:0.8;
 padding:2px;
}
.abiImg{
 margin-left:10px;
 position: relative;
 box-shadow: 0.3px 0.3px 0.3px #fff;
 top:117px;
 float:left;
 z-index:3;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainContainer">
 <table  background="drow_ranger_vert.jpg" style="height:270px;width:230px;z-index:0;">
 <div class="NameContainer"></div>
 <img alt="Agility" title="Agility" class="typeImg" src="overviewicon_agi.png" border="0" height="33" width="33">
 <span class="heroName"> Drow Ranger </span>
 <div class="SpellContainer"></div>
 <img alt="Frost Arrows" title="Frost Arrows" class="abiImg" src="drow_ranger_frost_arrows_hp2.png" border="0" height="45" width="45">
 <img alt="Gust" title="Gust" class="abiImg" src="drow_ranger_silence_hp2.png" border="0" height="45" width="45">
 <img alt="Precision Aura" title="Precision Aura" class="abiImg" src="drow_ranger_trueshot_hp2.png" border="0" height="45" width="45">
 <img alt="Marksmanship" title="Marksmanship" class="abiImg" src="drow_ranger_marksmanship_hp2.png" border="0" height="45" width="45"></table>

</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The only elements that can be directly contained within a `<table>` are `<thead>`, `<tfoot>`, `<tbody>` and `<tr>`. All other elements (`<div>`, `<img />`, `<span>` etc) must be contained within a `<td>` or `<th>`.

Comment: well i dont know about dat i saw someone suggesting to do something like this - and it hadthe best outcome so far - my orginal code dont contain the table tag